# Proceed some commands to the shell command in Perl

Tags: perl, visual-studio

I am new to Perl and want to send automatically some commands to the Perl shell window using a script. I am using Eclipse. Is there any possibility that I use its shell window to send the following command to it:

```
cd D:\MyTest\examples\
```

and then want to sen this

```
msbuild
```

I want to start Visual Studio project via Perl script automatically. This is why I am using msbuild. Because the command prompt has to go to the directory of VS project to run msbuild, then I need just give a command that says where is the VS project. I hope this explains my problem!

Would you please help me?

Comment: What environment are you on? When you say "proceed" what do you mean? Are you trying to pass arguments to a script?

Comment: Have you read any documentation? What have you tried to solve the problem?

Comment: @jkeuhlen Please see the edited version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking how to get launch a shell to execute both

```
cd D:\MyTest\examples\
```

and

```
msbuild
```

If so,

```
system("cd D:\\MyTest\\examples & msbuild");
```

That said, I suspect you actually want

```
system("D: & cd \\MyTest\\examples & msbuild");
```

In theory, you could also change the parent's current drive and directory, which will be inherited by the child.

```
chdir("D:\\MyTest\\examples");
system("msbuild");
```

Comment: Thanks a ot for your answer. Well, none of these do not change directory to the given folder and then could not recognize `msbuild`.

I have this error:
`'msbuild' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`